# I have a two imageView in a Relative Layout. Is it possible to change the Position of one imageview dynamically. while the other remain constant.?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have Two Image Views Defined in Xml. I want to Change the Position of One of them Dynamically while the Other remains constant.?? Any Suggestions. Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes off course, this is damn possible.Use LayouParam

```
        ImageView img1=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
    ImageView img2=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp2=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
    lp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT,img2.getId());
    img1.setLayoutParams(lp2);
```

**Setting Margin**

```
lp2.setMargins(Left, TOp, right,Bottom);
```

Comment: params should remain constant And the position will change relative to Image1 which is in the same relative layout.

Comment: So it can achieve.First get old height,width and set to Param.And you can as you want.If you want to set relative to image1 then also.I have edited my answer

Comment: Now you got?and if it help to solve your problem so please mark it answer

Comment: i really appreciate ur Efforts but either i did n't elaborate the problem rightly or you just misunderstood. Anyhow ,i got an idea to solve this problem bt i am wondering if i can use setMargin or Something programatically in case of Image VIew inside Relative layout.if this is possible then my problem would be solved

Comment: coz i want to move my image up and down relative to image1 which remain constant.

Comment: you can set margin and all by using LayoutParam.I will edit my answer to show how to setMargin.HopeFully it help you

Comment: And if you really want to appreciate me or other then just give a vote to answer or accept answer.For this every one is helping you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by providing new rules for `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`. Just do something like this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = imageView2.getLayoutParams();
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
imageView2.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: params should remain constant And the position will change relative to Image1 which is in the same relative layout

Comment: There is method `addRule(int, int)` - where first param is const value (like toRightOf, etc) and second param - id of view for rule usage.

Comment: you just misunderstood the problem sir ,i got an idea to solve this problem bt i am wondering if i can use setMargin or Something programatically in case of Image VIew inside Relative layout.if this is possible then my problem would be solved..thanx

Comment: i want to move image up and down with the press of button relative to the image 2

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume your imageView1 which would remain Constant is center aligned in parent. And Your Second ImageView imageView2 is aligned left to imageView1, and now you want to align it to below of imageView1. Use following to achieve the same,

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = imageView2.getLayoutParams();
param.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.imageView1);
imageView2.setLayoutParams(params);

Comment: i want to move image up and down with the press of button relative to the image 2

Answer (score 0):

Use the layout property like this:

```
imageView.layout(l,t,r,b);
```

Where the `l` stands for left, `t` for top, etc.