# Setting ImageViews in RelativeLayout in API Version 8

Tags: android, coordinates, android-relativelayout, android-imageview

I have created a basic `RelativeLayout` in my XML file. In my code, I want to dynamically create several `ImageView`s and place them at different locations within the `RelativeLayout`. Everything I've tried (`ImageView.setX()`, `ImageView.setTranslationX()`, `ImageView.setPadding()`) either says I need a higher API level (11+) or causes the `ImageView` to not appear.

If I do not try to do anything with the location of the `ImageView`, then the image does appear on the screen in the `(0,0)` position.

Comment: Have you taken a look at layoutparams? See for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876131/i-have-a-two-imageview-in-a-relative-layout-is-it-possible-to-change-the-positi and/or http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple app will layout 15 icons in three rows dynamically using RelativeLayout. There is no reason to use AbsoluteLayout - it is also deprecated.

The main activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private int mWidth;
    private int mTile;
    private int mColMax = 5;
    private Context mContext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mContext = this;

        // the screen width is need to work out the tile size
        mWidth = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        // how wide (and high) each icon will be to fit the screen.
        mTile = (mWidth / mColMax);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // layout the icons
        initUI();
    }

    /**
     * Layout 15 icon images in three rows dynamically.
     */
    private void initUI() {
        // this is the layout from the XML
        ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.main_layout); 

        ImageView iv;
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;

        int i = 0;
        int row = 0;
        int col = 0;
        do {
            params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(mTile,mTile);
            params.setMargins((col * mTile), (row * mTile), 0, 0);
            iv = new ImageView(mContext);
            iv.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            iv.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            iv.setLayoutParams(params);
            layout.addView(iv);
            if (col == mColMax) {
                row++;
                col = 0;
            } else {
                col++;
            }
        } while (++i <= 16);
    }
}
```

And the layout XML.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

RelativeLayouts are used to place items in relationship to other items.  YOu don't use them to place layouts at specific positions like a setX.  If you want to place the new item relative to existing items, look at RelativeLayout.LayoutParams-  you can set layout_alignXXX and layout_toXXXOf type parameters through them.

If you need an exact pixel position, use the deprecated AbsoluteLayout.  Just be aware its going to look ugly as heck on any device with a different aspect ratio or size screen without a ton of work.

Comment: If I am calculating everything dynamically, why can't I set a basic X & Y value?

Comment: Because RelativeLayout isn't designed to work that way.  AbsoluteLayout does.  It's deprecated, but it still works fine-  that was google's way of saying "We really don't want you to use this".

Comment: I disagree with Gabe. `AbsouluteLayout` is deprecated code and as such should not be used with new code. Besides that, `RelativeLayout` can be used to do exactly what you want. See my answer below.

Comment: He never says he wants 3 rows.  He says specific locations.  RelativeLayout cannot be done that way without some complete hacks.  And AbsoluteLayout is deprecated because they don't want you programming that way.  If you decide you have a good reason to there's absolutely no reason not to use it.  Or create your own version that does the same thing, but why waste your time doing that?  There are several application types that do need exact placement of elements to pixel locations.  Avoid it in most cases, but if its needed its needed.

Comment: As you say, `AbsouluteLayout` is deprecated. Don't use it. The 3 rows of 15 icons was simply an example. It is perfectly simple to layout any `View` to any position on the screen. There is nothing "hacky" about it - it is more "this is how it is done". For example, it is very simple math to convert the screen width to 100%, then position any `View` as a percentage of the screen width. Then position another `View` (using a %) relative to another. My example shows that using a based of 5 (or 20%) of the screen width.

Comment: So don't bring it up as an answer to his problem if it isn't what he asked.  RelativeLayout is not designed to work the way you used it.  Applying margins like that is a complete hack.  Margins go between elements, they are not supposed to be used as an absolute parameter from origin, overlapping entire elements.  Using a class designed to work that way, even if deprecated, is less of one by a long shot.  You're absolutely wrong on this.  But I'm going to drop this now, as we're not going to convince one another.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your statement "overlapping entire elements" is wrong. If you run the sample code and enable "Show GPU overdraw" and "Show layout bounds" you will see that there is in fact no overlapping at all. There is nothing hacky at all with using `setMargins()` like this. It is a `RelativeLayout` and everything within a `RelativeLayout` is "relative" to something, which is in turn "relative" to the origin point. Maybe if you run the sample code I will convince you :]